# Same number on every side of triangle?

Tags: geometry, arithmetic

Given the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9, sort them on this triangle, so that adding all the numbers of a triangle's side equals the same number.

[image: Triangle]

Comment: Hello, anybody there?

Comment: This is just a puzzle, not a math question. The sum of all the numbers is $45$, hence if $s$ is the sum of numbers on a side and $v$ is the sum of numbers in the vertices, $3s-2v=45$. Then, we just have to try a few configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are some people out here. I am just one of the most humble ones.

[image]

Comment: You are very smart sir! Thank you so much!